# Relative path in *.userlibraries file

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I need to path relative path in eclipse user library. When I do like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<eclipse-userlibraries version="2">
    <library name="libName">
        <archive path="API declaration format.js"/>
    </library>
</eclipse-userlibraries>
```

eclipse shows assertion:
[image]

I use ChromeDevTools to debug JavaScript. Do you have any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: Can you please show how this question is relevant to the Chrome DevTools? Right now I don't see how the tag fits since there is nothing here from it.

Comment: Chrome DevTools gives possibility to create user library for JavaScript projects.

Comment: Then please include steps as to what you are doing to cause this error. Just saying you "use devtools" without any context isn't enough to warrant tagging it as a DevTools problem.

Comment: Actually, I assume what problem is in eclipse. Steps to reproduce Window->Preferences->JavaScript(this is DevTools part)->Include Path->Import-> choose file which context provided above->OK->OK and eclipse shows error.